# PowerMock raises exception when @PrepareForTest annotation passes argument is child (extended) class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, tdd, powermock

I am using PowerMock for test my codes. I examined many test codes but I couldn't find the answer about the problem below. I also tried different version of power mock but did not work.

```
public class TestParent {

}

public class TestChild extends TestParent {

    public void foo() {
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        System.out.println(now.getDayOfYear());
    }

}
```

When I pass normal class to @PrepareForTest, test is working properly.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({TestParent.class})
public class ActionTest {

      @Test
      public void testFunc() {
          System.out.println("test !!!");
      }
  }
```

But when I pass TestChild it is raising an exception

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({TestChild.class})
public class ActionTest {

    @Test
    public void testFunc() {
        System.out.println("test !!!");
    }
}
```

> java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching [{ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=testFunc]
>       at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:40)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createFilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:83)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:74)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:49)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:526)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)

This is my pom file

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Following your steps above, I can't seem to reproduce the error in IntelliJ: Both tests complete. Maybe it's an specific Eclipse quirk?

Also, I got the following warning using the OpenJDK 14 GA:
```WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl (file:/D:/coding/tools/repo/org/powermock/powermock-reflect/2.0.4/powermock-reflect-2.0.4.jar) to method java.lang.Object.clone()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl```
[...]

Comment: @JoostPapendorp But there is no IDE specific tricks. It is weird. I'm using Eclipse.2020-03

Comment: To verify that, try running ```mvn clean test``` from the commandline, using the maven surefire plugin.
Side note: I found that using powermock usually points to a less than optimal (a.k.a. untestable) code. If all else fails, you could also try to refactor.